# Create a MySql database from an operation of a Java Web Service

Tags: java, mysql, database, web-services, jdbc

I want to have a Java Web Service which allows clients to connect and update a MySql database with their data. But how can i set up that database (using JDBC through my Java code) and a first table of it as soon as the Web Service is deployed and before any client connects? Is there any way to have an operation iny my code to do that?

Comment: I'm not sure I completely understand...you want your app to load a table when it starts?

Comment: @Max: yes that's what i want. To create a database and load a new table

Answer (score 1):

Why not have a script that is executed right before you deploy the web-service and executes something like:

```
create database `database_name`;
use `database_name`;
create table `table_name ... etc`
```

Whether you do this on Linux or Windows it's immaterial, the syntax as far as MySQL is concerned is identical; the only difference would be whether you have this on a batch file or a  shell script (in case you use Linux or Unix).

Your Java program does not need to be involved in this unless there's another reason you are not telling us. But if that's the case; you can send these SQL commands to MySQL from your Java program and have logic to execute them only if the database and table don't already exist. Obviously, you need to do this only once, when your application starts, but again, you did not provide enough details.

Comment: thanks for your answer! I want to do that from my Java program and specifically from the code of a Web Service. I want it to launch when the Web Service is deployed. How can i state such an operation in the code of the Web Service?